# How does Leechade interact with Bastion Bourbon?

Tags: bastion

The description for Bastion Bourbon says "Health tonics fully restore health." For Leechade, it says "-66% Health tonic potency."

I know it sounds like a simple question, but does this mean that that with both of these active, Health tonics will always heal exactly 34% of my health? Or do they interact in any some other way? For example, does one override the other and have only its effect active?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I tested this just now with my copy of Bastion and a save near the end of the game.  With both distillery options active, the amount of health I gained from drinking a health tonic was around 50% of my maximum health - it was certainly more than 34%, which is what I expected.

It was comparable to the effect from drinking a tonic when I had neither spirit active.  I'd say the positive effect of the Bastion Bourbon is cancelled out by the negative effect of the Leechade.

Comment: This tallies with my experiences since I asked the question. Not sure if they cancel each other out perfectly, but I suppose that's only important if you're down to 1% health, in which case I posit that you have bigger problems.

Comment: @Alex, yeah, I didn't get out a ruler (and I've got the Xbox version so I can't compare screenshots), but the effect was unusual enough that I thought "cancelling out" was probably close enough ;)

Answer (score 5):

I tested this myself and found that as long as Bastion Bourbon is equipped at an earlier level slot, it will entirely negate the negative effects of Leechade.